# Retrofit : how to send base64 encoded body request in POST

Tags: android, retrofit

I have recently started using Retrofit in my android application and this is my retrofit request to add a user:

```
RestAdapter mRestAdapter =  new RestAdapter.Builder()
        .setEndpoint(SERVER_URL)
        .setLogLevel(RestAdapter.LogLevel.FULL)
        .setRequestInterceptor(new SessionInterceptor())
        .setClient(new OkClient(new OkHttpClient()))
        .build();

@POST("/user/add")
    JsonElement registerUser(@Body User user);
```

Here User is the model class for the user which i want to register with the server. The issue is that the server expects the json body request in Base64.encode() format. Is there a way to send Base64 encoded data using retrofit?

I could think of manually doing it like this :

```
String json = gson.toJson(user);
byte[] bytes = Base64.encode(json.getBytes("UTF-8"), Base64.DEFAULT);
```

and then passing this in the request. But, I would have to do it manually and with every POST request. Is there a cleaner way to do this.

Comment: encoding a json string in base64? why would the anyone do that? Go see the person who did that and poke them until they give you a valid answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This answer applies directly to Retrofit v2.0 but the same concept can be adapted to earlier versions.

One option would be to create a `RequestInterceptor`. From the information you've provided, I'm not quite sure if *every* `POST` is to be base 64 encoded or not. I'm going to assume this is the case.

```
public class Base64EncodeRequestInterceptor implements Interceptor {

    @Override
    public Response intercept(Chain chain) throws IOException {
        Request originalRequest = chain.request();
        Request.Builder builder = originalRequest.newBuilder();

        if (originalRequest.method().equalsIgnoreCase(POST)) {
          builder = originalRequest.newBuilder()
              .method(originalRequest.method(), encode(originalRequest.body()));
        }


        return chain.proceed(builder.build());
    }

    private RequestBody encode(RequestBody body) {
        return new RequestBody() {
            @Override
            public MediaType contentType() {
                return body.contentType();
            }

            @Override
            public void writeTo(BufferedSink sink) throws IOException {
                Buffer buffer = new Buffer();
                body.writeTo(buffer);
                byte[] encoded = Base64.encode(buffer.readByteArray(), Base64.DEFAULT);
                sink.write(encoded);
                buffer.close();
                sink.close();
            }
        };
    }
}
```

What this interceptor does is check if the incoming method is a `POST` and if so, it will base64 encode the `RequestBody`.

Comment: Thanks. Since I already have an interceptor, I am planning to go ahead with this one. Another query - If i want to have something like this in the body- `resource=<some encoded string>&action=ADD` . For this can i use @Body or do i need to use @Mulitpart and then @Fields

Answer (score 2):

For general object types (String included) Retrofit is going to use its Converter to serialize the value. In this case, Gson is used by default to serialize the body as JSON.

In order to upload Base64-encoded data you want to use TypedInput. This tells Retrofit that you will pass it the raw body which is already serialized and an associated Content-Type value.